# How do I make my lightbox not scroll?

Tags: html, css

http://www.markthatred.com/ I have this site when you go to the my works section and click a thumbnail a lightbox will appear it's working fine but how can I make it not non-scrollable while it is on lightbox?

html

```
<!--  thumbnail image wrapped in a link  -->
<a href="#img1">
   <img alt="Eiffel Tower Web Design Mockup - Mark That RedWeb Design Mockup" class="works-feature-thumb" src="images/lightbox-1-t.jpg"/>
</a>
<!--  lightbox container hidden with CSS  -->
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
   <img alt="Law Attorney Web Design Mockup - Mark That Red Web Design Mockup Philippines" src="images/lightbox-1.jpg"/>
</a>
```

css

```
.lightbox {
    /** Default lightbox to hidden */
       display: none;

    /** Position and style */
      position: fixed;
       z-index: 999;
         width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
           top: 0;
          left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
    /** Pad the lightbox image */
     max-width: 95%;
    max-height: 90%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.lightbox img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.lightbox:target {
    /** Remove default browser outline */
    outline: none;

    /** Unhide lightbox **/
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this script it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".works-feature").click(function(){
        $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    });
    $(".lightbox").click(function(){
        $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @user2993018 - only if the lightbox is triggered and closed by clicks.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add an `overflow: hidden` to the html-element, as long as the lightbox is active. I don't know which lightbox you're using, but there are probably some callbacks like "onOpen" and "onClose":

Comment: Hi, the lightbox I got is pure css and those are the only code.

Comment: I see - then I'd recommend you to trigger the lightbox via JavaScript. Smth like this: `$(".works-feature").on('click', function() { $(this).addClass("show-lightbox"); $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); });` and remove the class again when clicking on the lightbox. Otherwise the scrolling won't work reliably.